# Question on query optimization in Oracle database - fetch first 1 rows only

Tags: database, oracle, cursor, query-optimization, query-performance

I have a cursor in oracle database which would be fetching thousands of rows in a sorted manner but I would actually need only the first row(i.e., oldest one first). The loop is designed in such a way that it processes first one row and comes out. And then the cursor is opened again to fetch the remaining rows. My question is if I use 'fetch first 1 rows only' in the cursor, could it really help improve performance?

Basically I want to know which is more efficient in terms of performance among the below:

**Query 1:**

```
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,a.rowid rid,a.col4
        from table1 a, table2 b
        where a.status = 'N'
        and b.col1 = 1
        and b.col2 = a.col5
        order by insert_time;
```

**Query 2:**

```
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,a.rowid rid,a.col4
        from table1 a, table2 b
        where a.status = 'N'
        and b.col1 = 1
        and b.col2 = a.col5
        order by insert_time
        fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Comment: Why do you think opening a cursor thousands of times, only to process 1 row each time, is better tha simply opening it once and looping through the results?  Update your question to show your _formatted_ code, and I'm certain someone will be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: Actually this is a badly performing code which I am trying to improve. The logic of opening cursor multiple times but processing only one row each time was probably done so as to pickup the records as and when they come in.

Comment: "Actually this is a badly performing code which I am trying to improve."  Then you are asking the wrong question.  What you should do is _show_ the code and ask how it can be improved. Instead you are fixating an one ill-conceived solution and asking how to make it work.  Every time you open the cursor, oracle has to _repeat_ locating _all_ of the subject rows. And you will never see records "as and when they come in".  you will only see rows that were COMMITed at the time your session began.

Comment: "The logic . . . was probably done so". That sounds like you inherited someone else's code, and them assume there was a good reason for it.  Don't make that assumption.  It is quite likely .. in this case almost a certainty ... that the previous person simply wasn't very good at writing code.

Answer (score 3):

Letting the database know your "intentions" (eg "I only want the first x rows") can be critical to performance. For example, normal sorting operations store the entire result set in memory or on disk in temporary tablespace. But with the `FETCH` clause Oracle knows it only has to track the Top N rows and can use significantly less memory for sorting.

Here's a complete video walkthrough of why including demos and the impact on response time, memory and performance.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhOVF82KY7E

Comment: From the video I understand that RAM usage will be reduced if we ask database to fetch fixed number of rows. But what if the execution time increases? In my case I am observing increase in execution time after adding  'fetch first 1 rows only'(not always but most of the runs). Can this be ignored? Is it still considered as improved performance?

Comment: check the execution plan with the 'fetch first' option. Sometimes you might be better off using the nested rownum optimization instead (ie, order-by within an inline view) and then rownum=1 on the outer query

Answer (score 1):

cursor processing  is a slow process, if you can do in SQL instead of using a cursor then try to use SQL to process the data.

What happens if you have more than one row to process, will you still go and process the row by going through the cursor more than one time ?

thanks

Comment: Yes, the cursor is being opened N number of times if there are N rows.

Comment: Hi, type of processing you are doing after you get the data from cursor ? Did you try using a SQL to do an update instead of using a cursor as Cursor will be a very very slow , it is generally recommended to use SQL if you can do DML. What

Comment: After fetching each row from the cursor, the process will fetch data from different tables to build an XML and then insert that XML into another table. I think I can not get rid of cursor here.